# Implementing Macros In Custom BizTalk Adapter

Tags: macros, biztalk, adapter, biztalk-2009

I am writing a custom adapter. I want to implement the macro functionality that the built in adapters have already.

It seems to me that there should be a library somewhere built into BizTalk or available else where that I can pass a string string to and it give me back the resulting string with macros replaced with their context data.

Am I crazy to think this? Does this exist? Thanks!

Comment: As Maxime mentioned there is nothing fancy in Macros, it's just the way you handle tokens in your customer adapter code.

Answer (score 3):

Implementing macros is heavily dependant upon the context of the adapter you are trying to implement. In fact, as far as I know, there is no builtin library to do this.

However, implementing macros is relatively easy, and you don't have to resort to Regular Expressions or such. A simple token replacement algorithm will do.

Implementing macros such as %DateTime% or %MessageID% is trivial and can be done without context. Implementing other macros, such as, %SourceFileName% would require your adapter to read BizTalk context properties.